# Busqueda mediante un query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy realizando un buscador para mi aplicación, es un formulario de búsqueda que maneja dos parámetros: por Ruta y por Producto, pero el usuario puede colocar un parámetro o puede colocar ambos en la búsqueda, mi problema es que si el usuario selecciona un parámetro, el otro parámetro es nulo y en el query me va a buscar donde dicho campo sea nulo. no me consigue los registros a no ser que envié ambos parámetros, como podría solucionar esto? aquí les dejo mi query:

```
   @ventas = Vent.joins('left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto')
                    .where('venta.IdEmpresa = ? AND venta.RutaId = ? AND detallevet.Articulo = ?',current_usuario.empresa_id, params[:search], params[:search3])
                    .distinct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primera cosa, en general es mala prática poner la consulta directo en el controlador, esa es lógica que le corresponde a la capa del modelo, así que el primer cambio que haría sería este:

```
  @ventas = Vent.search(params)
```

luego definir un método en tu modelo donde exista una consulta principal en la que van definidos los elementos comunes de la consulta. Luego vas agregando a ésta las consultas condicionales con `if` según lo vayas requieriendo:

```
  def self.search(params)
    query = joins('left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto')
            .where('venta.IdEmpresa = ?', current_usuario.empresa_id).distinct
    query = query.where('venta.RutaId = ?', params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
    query = query.where('detallevet.Articulo = ?', params[:search3]) if params[:search3].present?
    query
  end
```

Por defecto en activerecord las llamadas son de tipo *lazy*, así que mientras no se comience a iterar o revisar en general los resultados de una consulta, puedes seguir encadenando mas consultas.
Ahora, si quieres algo más, podrías usar [searchlight](https://github.com/nathanl/searchlight) que te permite construir búsquedas basado en los parámetros de búsqueda que vaya recibiendo desde el formulario. Prácticamente lo mismo que te expliqué en el ejemplo, pero mucho más ordenado.

Comment: Excelente Amigo Alter, muchísimas gracias por corregir mi error y solucionar mi problema, cada vez aprendiendo mas.

Answer (score 1):

**Espero que lo siguiente te de una idea clara de como podrías revólver ese problema.**

Lo que te recomendaría hacer en esa situación seria crear una serie de condiciones en las que identifiques si el parámetro RUTA viene básico pero el parámetro PRODUCTO si tiene algún valor el query va ser el siguiente:

```
@ventas = Vent.joins('left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto')
                    .where('venta.IdEmpresa = ? AND detallevet.Articulo = ?',current_usuario.empresa_id, params[:search3])
                    .distinct
```

En caso de que el parámetro PRODUCTO llegue vacío pero el parámetro RUTA este con agun valor  el query será el siguiente:

```
@ventas = Vent.joins('left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto')
                    .where('venta.IdEmpresa = ? AND venta.RutaId = ?',current_usuario.empresa_id, params[:search)
                    .distinct
```

En caso de que el usuario ponga los dos parametros llenos con algún valor el query será el siguiente:

```
@ventas = Vent.joins('left outer join detallevet on venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto')
                    .where('venta.IdEmpresa = ? AND venta.RutaId = ? AND detallevet.Articulo = ?',current_usuario.empresa_id, params[:search], params[:search3])
                    .distinct
```

De esa forma obtendrás los resultados de como deseas. ***No veo la necesidad de poner todo el código con las condiciones puesto que lo que en realidad necesitas es una idea de cómo solucionar ese problema, la implementación no creo sea mayor problema para ti.***

Comment: gracias por responder, la cosa es que no solo tengo esos dos parametros, en total son 4. y hacer un if con las diferentes alternativas como que estoy repitiendo mucho el codigo. deberia de existir alguna funcion o algo que me permita solo utilizar un query y que si el valor viene vacio que no lo tome en cuenta, seria lo mas optimo pienso yo